# How to bind to checked for a checkbox only?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox and I am using jquery. I want to popup a dialog box when a user checks the checkbox. However if they uncheck the box nothing should popup.

How can I do this? Also I need to use jquery live or livequery as the checkbox is not displayed on page load.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#checkbox').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        popUpFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm so you can't make a selector that only binds to checked checkboxes?

Comment: sure you can $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked') but this doesnt make sens to me, because checkboxes can change their status.

Comment: Note 2013, _live_ is now deprecated in favor of _on_ . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926